# Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException and Compiler Option

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, ssl, web

I am creating a web application with servlets in Java and I'm using classes type Jsoup based httpclient etc ... I have a problem with A CONNECTION SSL . MI from problems and gives me an exception to this: avax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException : handshake alert: unrecognized_name .

I found this solution:

```
System.setProperty ( " jsse.enableSNIExtension " , " false " ) ;
```

The problem is that if I start the project with the local tomcat works instead with my tomcat online on an OVH server is not working . I saw that there is another way anologo this but I did not understand . Maybe we need to set an attribute during compilation like this:

```
 = false -Djsse.enableSNIExtension.`
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by placing the code

```
System.setProperty(" jsse.enableSNIExtension","false");
```

in the app and restarting Tomcat
using the command: service tomcat7 restart

Comment: In other words you didn't find a compiler option.